# Confusion matrix terminology

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I am working on machine learning with a supervised problem with 2 classes: NO and YES, and I need some precision about confusion matrix. I read 2 differents terminologies, some writes matrix confusion as:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 &  &\text{Positive Prediction} &\text{Negative Prediction}\\ 
 &\text{Actual Positive Class}  &TP &FP \\ 
 &\text{Actual Negative class}  &FN &TN 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where TP = true positive, FP = false positive, FN = false negative, and TN = true negative.

And I also saw, the confusion matrix written like that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 &  &\text{Predicted NO} &\text{Predicted YES}\\ 
 &\text{Actual NO Class}  &TN &FP \\ 
 &\text{Actual YES class}  &FN &TP 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

TP and TN are inverted. Which one is corrected, especially for my problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this page](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/true-false-positive-negative) from Google's machine learning crash course explains true vs false and positive vs negative very well. In addition [the wikipedia page on the confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) is very informative. As you will see the second matrix is the correct one, since a false positive is an example that is incorrectly predicted as being positive.

Comment: Many thanks @Oxbowerce for your clear explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The first matrix is wrong. FP must be replaced by FN and vice versa.

Comment: for me, it was much more TP must be replaced by by TN and vice versa.